# String to Date with Format not being changed

Tags: java, datetime

I have formatted date in the form of string and i want it in date format without changing formatted pattern

here is my code

```
Date currDate = new Date();//Fri Oct 31 03:48:24 PDT 2014
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat formatter;
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String formattedDate= formatter.format(currDate);//2014-10-31 04:23:42
```

here am getting in "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" format and the same format i want it in date.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date paidDate = sdf.parse(formattedDate);

System.out.println(pattern + " " + paidDate);//Fri Oct 31 03:48:24 PDT 2014
```

but i am getting result as Fri Oct 31 03:48:24 PDT 2014, so pls help me to get result as 2014-10-31 04:23:42 in date format

Comment: A `Date` is a number of milliseconds since epoch; to modify the default output you need a `DateFormat.format` call.

Comment: But that returns me String where i need that in Date as well

Comment: Just use `sdf.format` when printing?

Comment: If you are using Java 8, you should consider to use `LocalDateTime` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the date as it is  when you do this:

```
System.out.println(pattern + " " + paidDate);
```

you need to use the format you are talking

```
System.out.println(pattern + " " + formatter.format(paidDate));
```

Comment: The value returned is String i need it to be Date

Comment: The date is already in the ***paidDate*** object... how do you print it is absolutely irrelevant to the object...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the expected result simply because `System.out.println(pattern + " " + paidDate)` calls `paidDate.toString()` behind the scene which means here `java.util.Date#toString()`. If you want to format the date call  `formatter.format(paidDate)`.

If you want to have your date properly formatted when you call `toString()`, you will have to create a sub class of `java.util.Date` to overwrite the `toString()` method in order to return the result of `formatter.format()`. Something like that:

```
public class MyDate extends Date {
   public String toString() {
     final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); 
     return formatter.format(this);
   }
}
```

Comment: formatter.format() returns String, i need to be Date

Comment: If so you need to create a sub class of java.util.Date to overwrite the toString() method in order to return the result of formatter.format()